# What's difference between ".SECTION .data" and just ".data" in GNU GAS?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

It seems that both are working.

But what does that `.SECTION` mean? Why is it uppercase?

I couldn't find out any difference in gdb 'info file' or 'disassemble main'

Answer (score 2):

**Why is it uppercase?**

Assembly directives seem to be case insensitive based on:

- quick compilation tests
- the [docs saying](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html) "The rest of the name is letters, usually in lower case."
- my interpretation of the source at [read.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/read.c;h=9fd0335d8e1f3e9844e2326d36418c79dcdc6b33;hb=68b975af7ef47a9d28f21f4c93431f35777a5109#l983)

  - which uses a `TOLOWER` on both directives and instructions if `TC_CASE_SENSITIVE` is undefined
  - which `git grep` says is the case for all archs except `metag` in binutils 2.25

Now for `.data` vs `.section .data`.

**Docs**

The [docs for `.section`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Section.html) say that:

> This directive is only supported for targets that actually support arbitrarily named sections; on a.out targets, for example, it is not accepted, even with a standard a.out section name.

so this is less portable and more configurable, as you can pass custom flags to it to control the section properties with the arguments

```
.section name [, "flags"[, @type[,flag_specific_arguments]]]
```

**Empirical test**

A quick test on GAS 2.24 ELF Linux x86-64 shows that they give the same output for a simple input:

a.S:

```
.data
    i: .int 1
```

b.S:

```
.section .data
    i: .int 1
```

Compare:

```
as -o a.o a.S
as -o b.o b.S
cmp a.o b.o
echo $?
```

**Source code**

For ELF, `.section` it is handled by [config/obj-elf.c#obj_elf_section()](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/config/obj-elf.c;h=e2ef99e28d2c6ded702c66b05d1c79452e198a6c;hb=68b975af7ef47a9d28f21f4c93431f35777a5109#l90)

`.data` is handled by [read.c#s_data](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/read.c;h=9fd0335d8e1f3e9844e2326d36418c79dcdc6b33;hb=68b975af7ef47a9d28f21f4c93431f35777a5109#l1877).

TODO: conclude from the source if `.section .data` without any arguments does the same as `.data` or not

Answer (score 0):

.section seems to be directive for defining a section with name and/or flags.
.data is predefined section for initialized data.

This is just a guess, but I think .section .data might be two sections one after another: the first is unnamed with no flags and no contents, the other one is the .data-section.

Comment: According to `objdump`, `.section .data` creates a single section named `.data`.